# Customize a JList

Tags: java, swing, customization, jlist

I'm fairly new to Java, and while constructing a GUI application, I discovered I require a JList that has column headers, almost similar to the DataGridView in C#.

So: How does one customize a control or create a control to allow for such a thing? I assume the simplest way would be to add labels into the component somehow. What are some approaches I can take?

Comment: I would not use a JList but instead use a JTable, especially if I needed multiple columns and headers. Even if I only needed one column, a JTable can act as a super JList offering all that JList has and then some including the ability to use cell editors in addition to cell renderers.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with Java!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you probably want to look at a `JTable` instead of a `JList` if you want headers. Since you asked for guidance, the best we can do is provided you with the link to the [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), in particular the [`JTable` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

A name-drop of the most important concepts of working with tables will not hurt either. Like some of the other Swing components, a `JTable` has a view and model side. The [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) represents the view side and the [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) the model side. The representation of the model-objects in the view is handled by the [`TableCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html)